# How to display latest DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I guess i am doing some basic mistake when creating these dialogs as i couldn't find any questions on the issue i am having.

I am trying to show the latest dialogs (introduced from 3.0 for time and date) in my application and i followed the link from [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html). My application supports only devices from 4.0 and above, so this shouldn't be a problem.

I thought, when i click on the button to invoke the date or time picker, i will be seeing something like below...

[image]

But, here is what i am getting... which i think is a old Date Picker

[image]

My XML for button that triggers the dialog..

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_end_date"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="@string/button_enddate" />
```

For the java part, i added the code from the developer's site and i guess that's not needed here.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What Android version are you using? The first datepicker and timepicker are only available in Holo Theme enabled Devices (11+). To use Holo Theme on < 11 devices, you can use `HoloEverywhere` library.

Comment: I guess this might be the issue. Previously the app used ABS and now i am porting it for only new devices. I will change and get back to you.

Comment: Idk, but you don't need ABS anymore, `appcompat v7` library already include `ActionBar` support for old devices. Are you sure that you are running the app in Android 11+ device?

Comment: Ya i don't need ABS, but i haven't yet changed it from ABS. This was a very old implementation and hence i used ABS at that time. Right now, i dont even need compat as i only support 4.0 and above

Comment: Can you post your `styles.xml` file? Your Themes have `Theme.Holo.*` parent? Can you check this?

Comment: Yeah, i think i got the idea of what i am doing wrong.. I was using Sherlock theme in my app till now. I am changing that. Please post your comment as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using Holo Theme, your Application theme in `styles.xml` must have `Theme.Holo.*` parent.

Like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light"> ... </style>
or
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo"> ... </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pickers like most of the views in android are dependent on the os version. Very simple UI elements like buttons look so visually different in gingerbread and kitkat version of the OS. There is very little you can do about it except changing styles if you are using a native picker. But you mentioned that you are using 4.0+ so it seems a little strange that you are getting an old dialog I tried that code myself and I got similar results. I can only propose some suggestions:

1. Add datepicker and time picker in your xml itself. It doesnot need to be a class that extends DialogFragment
2. try customizing your theme
3. `DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)`
   // you can set a theme for your date picker dialog too.
   Heres some snapshot of my code:
   [image]
   Note that you dont have set and cancel buttons by default. You have only done button.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably setting a wrong style to your application or activity. In my case I was using for each activity in Manifest a android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" theme. 
I am now using a custom app theme and it's working:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```